# PL/SQL Copy/insert multiple rows to one row in another table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, insert

I'm relatively new to SQL so forgive my ignorance...

I have three tables, SRS_CAP, SRS_IPF and SRS_URA.

I would like to copy data from SRS_IPF to SRS_URA where (some of) the primary keys of SRS_IPF equal those of SRS_CAP.

Specifically, and this is where my problem arises, I want to copy multiple rows from SRS_IPF to one row in SRS_URA. The script below illustrates what I want to achieve, but isn't intended to work - there must be a more efficient method (and one that actually works!):

```
INSERT INTO srs_ura
        (ura_stuc, ura_seqn, ura_stat, ura_name, ura_orgn, ura_add1)
SELECT ipf_ipuc, mySEQ, 'GP',
      (SELECT ipf_valu
                  FROM srs_ipf
                 WHERE ipf_code = 'IPQ_REF1TIT'
                   AND ipf_ippc = CAP_MCRC
                   AND ipf_ipuc = CAP_STUC),
      (SELECT ipf_valu
                  FROM srs_ipf
                 WHERE ipf_code = 'IPQ_REF1ORG'
                   AND ipf_ippc = CAP_MCRC
                   AND ipf_ipuc = CAP_STUC,
      (SELECT ipf_valu
                  FROM srs_ipf
                 WHERE ipf_code = 'IPQ_REF1AL1'
                   AND ipf_ippc = CAP_MCRC
                   AND ipf_ipuc = CAP_STUC)
 FROM srs_ipf, srs_cap
 WHERE ipf_ippc = CAP_MCRC AND ipf_ipuc = CAP_STUC;
```

As you can see - I want to repeatedly insert the ipf_valu field into multiple columns in srs_ura, but where the ipf_code of the same row in srs_ipf differs.

So my question is, what area of SQL programming should I be researching, to achieve the above?

I have further issues regarding auto-sequencing and NCLOBs but I'll tackle those later. I'm on Oracle server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this select return the rows you want to insert?

```
SELECT ipf_ipuc, /*mySEQ,*/ 'GP',
       MAX(CASE WHEN ipf_code = 'IPQ_REF1TIT' THEN ipf_valu END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN ipf_code = 'IPQ_REF1ORG' THEN ipf_valu END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN ipf_code = 'IPQ_REF1AL1' THEN ipf_valu END)
 FROM srs_ipf, srs_cap
 WHERE ipf_ippc = CAP_MCRC AND ipf_ipuc = CAP_STUC
   AND ipf_code IN ('IPQ_REF1TIT', 'IPQ_REF1ORG', 'IPQ_REF1AL1')
 GROUP BY ipf_ipuc
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I get an invalid identifier error unfortunately

Comment: Help me help you: can you post a minimal table description with the relevant columns and a few rows in each tables and the expected result ? :)

Comment: Ah I see - I've substituted srs_ipf (table_name) for ipf_valu (field) and get the results I'm after. So can I assume I can create some sort of view and copy the data that way? Thanks again

Comment: You're right, I got confused with the column name. If this select returns the row as you want them inserted, then you can `INSERT INTO (SELECT ...)` (no need for a view)

Comment: Vincent you're a genius - thanks very much for the help. Just got to overcome my sequence increment issue and I'll be away.